# how to save devexpress xtra report in database or file and load it from database or file

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I am developing a product application. It is windows form application using devexpress control. This application is a billing application.

My clients wants to design custom invoice format. If I add reports in my visual studio project then I have to deploy all reports to all clients. I want to deploy the report that is developed specific for the client. 
To do this I want a way that I can save Xtrareport as a file or in database. So that I can load it on runtime dynamically.

Is there anyway to do this ?

Environment :
C# 4.5 WinForms
DevExpress 14.2.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can save a report to a file or into a db
    using System.IO;
    using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
    // ...

```
// Save a report to a file. 
private string StoreReportToFile(XtraReport report){
    string path = "C:\\MyReport.repx";
    report.SaveLayout(path);
    return path;
}

// Save a report to a stream. 
private MemoryStream StoreReportToStream(XtraReport report){
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    report.SaveLayout(stream);
    return stream;
}
```

And load it

```
using System.IO;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
// ... 

// Load a report from a file. 
private void LoadReportFromFile(XtraReport report, string filePath){
    if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
        report.LoadLayout(filePath);
    } 
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("The source file does not exist.");
    }
}

// Load a report from a stream. 
private void LoadReportFromStream(XtraReport report, MemoryStream stream){
    report.LoadLayout(stream);
}

// Create a report from a file. 
private XtraReport CreateReportFromFile(string filePath){
    XtraReport report = XtraReport.FromFile(filePath, true);
    return report;
}

// Create a report from a stream. 
private XtraReport CreateReportFromStream(MemoryStream stream){
    XtraReport report = XtraReport.FromStream(stream, true);
    return report;
}
```

You can find more info here: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2592

Comment: your answer is really helpful. I am trying this and will set this as an answer.